# Render a partial based on model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just wondering if there is a way to make the following code more concise

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render partial: "#{user.state}_user", locals: { user: user } %>
<% end %>
```

Each user has a state (either `active` or `inactive`) and, for each user, there correct partial (`_active_user.hmtl.erb` or `_inactive_user.html.erb` needs to be rendered).

Looking for using `collection` but I can't find any sample.

Answer (score 1):

You could override [`ActiveModel::Conversion#to_partial_path`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html#method-i-to_partial_path) which is how render looks up the partial implicitly:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def to_partial_path
     "users/#{state}_user"
  end
end
```

But that will override how its rendered implicitly everywhere which may not be desirable.  Otherwise I would question if you really need to make this more succinct - what you are doing is off the rails and its better to have code that clearly shows its intent instead of something overly clever / force DRYied.

The reason you haven't found any examples using collection is that its not going to work. It iterates through the collection and calls `#to_partial_path` on each member.

Comment: Thanks or the reply. I don't like the idea to override `to_partial_path` especially because it is in the Model which should not care about views (I could put it in a presenter though).

I was just looking for an option for `collection` if available.